# Linux Shell Script to run commands in each subdirectory

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to make a shell script that can go through all of the subdirectories in an images/ folder and run a conversion utility from ImageMagick.

I can get the script to work fine in a single folder but can't get the syntax correct to run it from the top directory.

```
# convert a series of *.png images to *.svg
# images/subfolder1
# images/subfolder2
# etc.

for dir in `ls /*`;
do
    for x in `ls -1 /*.png`
    do
        y=`echo $x | cut -d "." -f1`
        echo "convert $x into $y.svg"
        convert $x $y.svg

    done  

done
```

What would be the correct way to get this done?

Comment: take a look at find and the -exec option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming the script is run from the `images` directory:*

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for p in */*.png; do
    s="${p/.png/.svg}"
    echo "converting $p into $s"
    # convert "$p" "$s"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will get far better performance, readability and simplicity using GNU Parallel like this:

```
find . -name \*.png | parallel convert {} {.}.svg
```

Why pay for all those lovely Intel cores and only use one of them?

Comment: Cool. I think I will start using parallel more often!

Comment: @EugeniuRosca It's excellent when you have 50,000+ images to process. Add `-eta` after `parallel` to get expected completion time, or `-j 32` to run 32 jobs at once - great with high latency things like `ping`.

Comment: I assume you speak from experience, looking at your "about" section :D Making use of those many cores is paramount nowadays, so I'll follow your suggestions. There are not so many people I know combining unix with photography! take care! :D

Answer (score 1):

By the way the same thing with makefile:

```
pngs = $(wildcard */*.png)
svgs = $(pngs:.png=.svg)

all: $(svgs)

%.svg: %.png
    @echo $@ $^
```

This also can be run in parallel with `make -j`

Comment: Totally unexpected. But why not?